# Брутфорс пароля c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, пароль, брутфорс

Есть задание, сделать брутфорс пароля используя словарь. Есть код генератора паролей:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* fname = "wordlist.txt";
    /* Parse command-line arguments */
    int max = 1;
    int key;
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        max = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    /* Open word list file */
    ifstream input;
    input.open(fname);
    if(input.fail())
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open " << fname << endl;
    }

    /* Read to end and load words */
    vector<string> wordList;
    string line;
    while(getline(input, line))
    {
        wordList.push_back(line);
    }

    /* Seed from random device */
    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine gen;
    gen.seed(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, wordList.size() - 1);

    /* Output as many passwords as required */
    const int pwLen = 3;
    int wordId, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < pwLen; j++)
        {
            cout << wordList[dist(gen)] << ((j != pwLen - 1) ? "_" : "");
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Собственно, на выходе получаем что-то типа `sdf_a_safasfasfasdf`. Как можно реализовать с этого подбор пароля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> да, это задание на лабораторную работу. Код можно и используя
> рекурсивные функции, но к сожалению, я в них не силен. Скорее всего я
> неправильно объяснил суть задания. Первоначально, надо создать
> брутфорс, который берет из словаря 3 слова. Между словами вместо
> пробела ставит "". И сравнивает с введенным паролем (он генерируется
> по такому же принципу, 3 слова из словаря и ""). Генератор то есть, но
> как реализовать брут - не могу понять. Извините если неправильно
> выразился в первый раз ;) – Boredix 5 минут назад

Для удобства вынес в другой комментарий

Итак, теперь задание стало более понятным и более узким

1. есть словарь слов
2. из словаря выбирается ТОЛЬКО 3 слова, которые соединяются разделителем (пустой символ? или все таки "_" было в коде?)
3. сравнивается с тестовым паролем и определяется - могло ли оно быть сгенерировано из словаря согласно установленным правилам

Если так, то код будет простым и без рекурсий:

```
// заполнить массив слов
std::vector<std::string> wordList;

// пароль с которым надо сравнивать
const std::string password = "password";

// непосредственно алгоритм брутфорса

for (const std::string& word1 : wordList)
{
    for (const std::string& word2 : wordList)
    {
        for (const std::string& word3 : wordList)
        {
            // собрать слово через разделитель "_"
            const std::string brutforced = word1 + std::string("_") + word2 + std::string("_") + word3;

            // сравнить с паролем и в случае совпадения - выйти
            if (password == brutforced)
            {
                std::cout << "Пароль удовлетворяет требованиям" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

в каком виде код принимается я не знаю - так что область сравнения надо допиливать (надо возвращать значение или писать на экране что-то - в общем зависит от задачи)

данный код можно существенно соптимизировать - если часть строки уже не соответствует слову из словаря, то не продолжать поиск дальше, тогда код будет таким (он даже более универсальный будет (если не ограничиваться только 3 словами в пароле):

```
// заполнить массив слов
std::vector<std::string> wordList;

// пароль с которым надо сравнивать
const std::string password = "password";

// непосредственно алгоритм брутфорса

// подбирать слова из словаря к паролю будем продвигаясь слева направо по паролю, пока не достигнем его края
int pos = 0;
while (pos < password.size())
{
    // ищем слово в словаре, которое совпадает с частью пароля начиная с позиции pos
    int new_pos = -1;
    for (const std::string& word : wordList)
    {
        // если текущее слово не является частью пароля - перейти к следующему
        if (strncmp(password.c_str() + pos, word.c_str(), word.size()) != 0)
            continue;

        new_pos = pos + word.size();

        // если найденным словом пароль не заканчивается, то проверить на наличие соединяющего символа '_' и если символ не найден - считать найденное слово неподходящим
        // это защита от ситуации, когда password = 'abc_xyz', а в словаре есть слова 'ab' и 'abc'
        if (new_pos < password.size() && password[new_pos] != '_')
            new_pos = -1;
        else
            break;
    }

    // если слово не было найдено - выйти
    if (new_pos == -1)
        break;

    pos = new_pos;  
} 

// если удалось дойти до конца пароля, значит успех
if ((pos == password.size()) 
{
    std::cout << "Пароль удовлетворяет требованиям" << std::endl;
}
```

Слегка изменил код чтобы учесть возможные ошибки

```
// заполнить массив слов
std::vector<std::string> wordList;
wordList.push_back("abc");
wordList.push_back("def");

// пароль с которым надо сравнивать
const std::string password = "abc_def_def";

// непосредственно алгоритм брутфорса

// подбирать слова из словаря к паролю будем продвигаясь слева направо по паролю, пока не достигнем его края
int pos = 0;
while (pos < password.size())
{
    // ищем слово в словаре, которое совпадает с частью пароля начиная с позиции pos
    int new_pos = -1;
    for (const std::string& word : wordList)
    {
        // если текущее слово не является частью пароля - перейти к следующему
        if (strncmp(password.c_str() + pos, word.c_str(), word.size()) != 0)
            continue;

        new_pos = pos + word.size();

        if ((new_pos < password.size() - 1) && (password[new_pos] == '_'))
        {
            new_pos += 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // если слово не было найдено - выйти
    if (new_pos == -1)
        break;

    pos = new_pos;
}

// если удалось дойти до конца пароля, значит успех
std::cout << ((pos == password.size()) ? "success" : "failed") << std::endl;

_getch();
```

Comment: В общем, интегрировал Ваш код с доработками в своей части. Теперь проверка идет, но проблема в том что Ваша часть кода ничего не выводит в конце. Дебаггером проверил - действительно 3 части кода находит, но после этого уходит дебаггер уходит в ассемблер (return 0). Создал новый ответ с полным кодом.

Comment: @Boredix, странно - std::cout у меня есть - до него не доходит или он не выполняется?

Comment: Он именно не выполняется. По дебаггеру ищет пароль правильно, но на 3 правильной части - программа просто заканчивает работу.

Comment: @Boredix, в текущий ответ добавил скорректированный код - дело было в проверке последнего входящего слова, я это переделал, теперь все работает - проверил на пароле `abc_def_def` - в примере указал его

Comment: Все отлично! Протестировал - работает как часики! Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Ну давайте разберемся как именно генерируется пароль

1. сначала выбирается сколько слов из словаря будет выбрано для пароля - переменная `max` (по умолчанию 1)
2. далее из словаря выбирается слово
3. слово дублируется 3 раза, причем после последнего дублирования ставится "_"

Правда `sdf_a_safasfasfasdf` с таким алгоритмом не получится, скорее должно было бы получиться `sdfsdfsdf_aa_`

Чтобы забрутформить надо воспроизвести тот же самый алгоритм, только перебрать все слова из словаря:

```
// формируем очередное звено пароля
void prepare(std::string& text, const std::string& pass, const int level, const int max_level, const std::vector<std::string>& dict) {
    // если сформировано уже максимальное кол-во звеньев - проверить пароль и - выйти
    if (level >= max_level) {
        if (gen == pass)
            std::cout << "Пароль найден!";

        return;
    }

    // перебрать все слова в словаре для данного звена пароля:
    const int pwLen = 3;

    for (const std::string& word: dict) {
        std::string tmp_res = res;
    
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index ++)
            res += word + ((index < pwLen - 1) ? "" : "_");

        // сформировать следующее звено пароля
        prepare(tmp_res, pass, level + 1, max_level, dict);
    }
}

std::string res = "";
prepare(res, "sdfsdfsdf_aa_xxx_", 0, 3, dict);
```

Если размер пароля (кол-во слов из словаря) не фиксировано, тогда будет выглядеть чуть по другому:

Надо проверять пароль после генерации всегда, а `max_level` использовать просто для ограничения максимального размера пароля

```
// формируем очередное звено пароля
void prepare(std::string& text, const std::string& pass, const int level, const int max_level, const std::vector<std::string>& dict) {
    // проверить пароль
    if (gen == pass) {
        std::cout << "Пароль найден!";
        return;
    }

    // если сформировано уже максимальное кол-во звеньев - выйти
    if (level >= max_level) {    
        return;
    }

    // перебрать все слова в словаре для данного звена пароля:
    const int pwLen = 3;

    for (const std::string& word: dict) {
        std::string tmp_res = res;
    
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index ++)
            res += word + ((index < pwLen - 1) ? "" : "_");

        // сформировать следующее звено пароля
        prepare(tmp_res, pass, level + 1, max_level, dict);
    }
}

std::string res = "";
prepare(res, "sdfsdfsdf_aa_xxx_", 0, 1000, dict);
```

Для оптимизации надо сделать так, чтобы если пароль найден на каком-то этапе, то дальше не продолжать работу:

```
// формируем очередное звено пароля
bool prepare(std::string& text, const std::string& pass, const int level, const int max_level, const std::vector<std::string>& dict) {
    // проверить пароль
    if (gen == pass) {
        std::cout << "Пароль найден!";
        return true;
    }

    // если сформировано уже максимальное кол-во звеньев - выйти
    if (level >= max_level) {    
        return false;
    }

    // перебрать все слова в словаре для данного звена пароля:
    const int pwLen = 3;

    for (const std::string& word: dict) {
        std::string tmp_res = res;
    
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index ++)
            res += word + ((index < pwLen - 1) ? "" : "_");

        // сформировать следующее звено пароля
        const bool is_success = prepare(tmp_res, pass, level + 1, max_level, dict);

        // если пароль был найден - ничего уже не делать
        if (is_success == true)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый и подробный ответ! Но есть проблема, мой компилятор (использую среду Xcode) не хочет импортировать Ваш код. Я импортирую его в конец своего, и получаю Function definition is not allowed here.

Comment: @Boredix, это тестовое задание? т.е. надо написать код не используя рекурсивный вызов функций?

Comment: да, это задание на лабораторную работу. Код можно и используя рекурсивные функции, но к сожалению, я в них не силен. Скорее всего я неправильно объяснил суть задания. Первоначально, надо создать брутфорс, который берет из словаря 3 слова. Между словами вместо пробела ставит "_". И сравнивает с введенным паролем (он генерируется по такому же принципу, 3 слова из словаря и "_"). Генератор то есть, но как реализовать брут - не могу понять. Извините если неправильно выразился в первый раз ;)

Answer (score 1):

Вот код с дополнениями. Проверка работает исключительно в дебаг режиме, никаких результатов в конце не выводит.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* fname = "wordlist.txt";

    /* Parse command-line arguments */
    int max = 1;
    int key;
    if(argc == 2) {
        max = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    /* Open word list file */
    ifstream input;
    input.open(fname);
    if(input.fail()) {
        cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open " << fname << endl;
    }

    /* Read to end and load words */
    vector<string> wordList;
    string line;
    while(getline(input, line)) {
        wordList.push_back(line);
    }

    /* Seed from random device */
    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine gen;
    gen.seed(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, wordList.size() - 1);

    /* Output as many passwords as required */
    const int pwLen = 3;
    string password = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < pwLen; j++) {
            password += (string)(wordList[dist(gen)] + ((j != pwLen - 1) ? "_" : ""));
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << password;
 

   // подбирать слова из словаря к паролю будем продвигаясь слева направо по паролю, пока не достигнем его края
   int pos = 0;
   while (pos < password.size())
   {
       // ищем слово в словаре, которое совпадает с частью пароля начиная с позиции pos
       int new_pos = -1;
       for (const std::string& word : wordList)
       {
           // если текущее слово не является частью пароля - перейти к следующему
           if (strncmp(password.c_str() + pos, word.c_str(), word.size()) != 0)
               continue;

           new_pos = pos + word.size();

           // если найденным словом пароль не заканчивается, то проверить на наличие соединяющего символа '_' и если символ не найден - считать найденное слово неподходящим
           // это защита от ситуации, когда password = 'abc_xyz', а в словаре есть слова 'ab' и 'abc'
           if (new_pos < password.size() && password[new_pos] != '_')
               new_pos = -1;
           else
               break;
       }

       // если слово не было найдено - выйти
       if (new_pos == -1)
           break;

       pos = new_pos;
   }

   // если удалось дойти до конца пароля, значит успех
   if ((pos == password.size()))
   {
       std::cout << "Пароль удовлетворяет требованиям" << std::endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```